# How to discover intent names within an existing Android application? (specifically Facebook)

Tags: android, facebook

I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus Android phone and for whatever reason the Facebook app's menu UI is missing. This means I cannot get to the Settings screen. I figure I can start the intent from my own app, but how do I find the intent name? I've looked in the APK, but the manifest appears to be compiled into a binary format.

Does anyone know the intent name for the Facebook settings activity?

How can I get a list of the intents in an APK?

----------- Update -----------

The Facebook app's manifest includes:

```
<manifest android:versionCode="4130"
android:versionName="1.6.3"
package="com.facebook.katana"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<activity android:label="@string/home_settings"
android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
```

I've got this in my code:

```
public void goToFacebookSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
        "com.facebook.katana.SettingsActivity");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But this fails with:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent
{ act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.facebook.katana/.SettingsActivity }
```

Is this an inherent limitation, or can I comply with the security requirements in some way?

Comment: Regarding the manifest: You could always use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to reverse engineer and convert the manifest back into plain, old XML. If you want to go that way.

Comment: That's helped me get to the next step, thanks. I've updated the question with where I'm at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<activity android:label="@string/home_settings"
android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
```

This activity doesn't declare any intent-filters. It also doesn't have the `android:exported` attribute set to `true`. Which means it can only be launched by the Facebook app or an app that has the same user ID since it's considered for app-internal use only.

See the [`android:exported` attribute documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) for more information.

---

Since this is for your personal use, you might be able to edit that attribute into the manifest and rebuild the application *(also using apktool)*.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR you can use explicit activity invocation only inside of your apk -  no way to call externally something that is not advertised.